# Notation: how to construct a set with upper bound and lower bound?

Tags: notation

For example,

set $A = \left \{ 1, 5, 10, 30 \right \} \in \mathbb{R}^N$

r = $10$

How do I write down a set which takes $A - r$ as lower bound, and $A + r$ as upper bound, containing ranges?

like:

set $C = (A - r)?(A+r) = \left \{ [-9,11], [-5,15], [0,20], [20, 40] \right \} \in \mathbb{R}^?$

Are there any notation that could describe such $?$ operation?

If I want to know if a number is in $C$

Is it okay to use, for example $(A-r)<m<(A+r)$?

Comment: Something like that would be okay, but it's not clear what the $\dots$ means.  Is there a pattern we're supposed to recognize?  If so, I don't see it.  Does it just mean "and some other intervals?"  Is it intended that the sets be infinite?  There needs to be some context that addresses these questions.

Comment: @saulspatz I just updated the question, and clearfy my point. the ... doesn't matter, I deleted it. The sets themself don't have patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write $C=\{[a-r,a+r]\mid a\in A\}$  When you say, "I want to know if a number is in $C$," I think you must mean "I want to know if some number is in an element of $C$."  The elements of $C$ are intervals not numbers, so it really doesn't make sense to ask if a number is in $C$.

There are (at least) two ways to express this. $$\exists c\in C(m\in c)\\ \text{ or }\\ m\in \bigcup_{c\in C} {c}$$  The question marks are not usually used in math, except on the blackboard.  You would write, "Is it true that...?"

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question correctly, you start with a point $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$. In your example $N=4$. $A$ is a *point* in that space, not a set.

What you want is the "cube" in $\mathbb{R}^N$ (same $N$) consisting of all the points each coordinate of which differs from the corresponding entry in $A$ by at most $r$.

In your example you could describe that as the product
$$
[−9,11] \times [−5,15] \times [0,20] \times [20,40].
$$

Note: my answer isn't the same as @saulspatz . I think we have interpreted your question differently.